# getting the id's of content pack dashboard using Power BI's REST API

Tags: powerbi

I want to use Power BI's REST API in order to get the dashboard id's of the dashboards I've created using a content pack.
I couldn't find a relevant property in the API. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have a property for this available. Any more details on the scenario you are trying to achieve. It could ve something that goes on our backlog.